# How to tell python to ignore items between two items in a list

Tags: python

I'm learning python and I'm having trouble a practice task I'm doing. The task wants the user to write a function that looks through a list and ignores the values that occur between a 6 and 9. However, for all other items not between a 6 and a 9, it outputs their sum.

I've tried to make a the program using a for loop and a while loop. However, I'm stuck at the part where I have to specify the range of the item. I understand that I should use a while loop within a for loop to solve the problem.

```py
def addoutside(arrg):
    num1 = 0
    for num in arrg:
        while num != 6:
            num1 = num1 + num
        while num == 6:
            for num2 in range(num):
                if.....

    addoutside(4,5,6,7,8,9,9)
    addoutside(4,5,6,7,8,9,9,10)
    addoutside(4,5,6,7,8,9,9,6,5,4,3)
    addoutside(1,2,3,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,6,7,9)
```

EDIT: I've clarified how I want the function to run by providing some examples of a few outputs.

```
Expected output: 18 <---- from the 4+5+9
Expected output: 28 <---- from the 4+5+9+10
Expected output: 36 <---- from the 4+5+9+6+5+4+3
Expected output: 12 <---_ from the 1+2+3+1+2+3
```

The 18 should be from the 4 + 5 + 9. The function should only ignore characters that occur between a 6 and a 9. Starting at the 6 and ending at the next 9.

Comment: (Also, wild guess that the problem wants you to exclude _numbers greater than or equal to 6 and less than or equal to 9_)

Comment: The last 9 shouldn't be excluded. I guess that wasn't clear in the question. Thought I made it clear when 8 showed the expected output to be 18.

Comment: My fault, I meant included.

Comment: no worries, anu ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: @Ved. Could you please update with a couple more examples? Also, what happens when a 6 is not followed by a 9 at any point?

Comment: Also, what would happen if there's another couple of 6 and 9 (i.e. 1,2,3,6,1,9,1,6,1,9)? Should the later 6 and 9 be summed too?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I've updated the original question with more examples to show what an expected output should be like.

Comment: @Chris for the example you mentioned (1,2,3,6,1,9,1,6,1,9), the output should be 7. It should ignore numbers between all instances of 6 and 9 including the 6 and 9.

Comment: @VedBrahmbhatt. Thanks for clarifying (and making your question answerable). You should select calestini's answer by clicking on the check mark next to it, as it is the correct answer. Dev Khadka also has a valid answer. I will be deleting mine now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

1. create two cumulative sums, one temporary and one final
2. The temporary will hold values when the sequence sees a 6. If the sequence never sees a 9, it will add back to the final cumulative sum.
3. create a flag for when it sees number `6`, this way we know we entered this sequence.
4. reset the flag when it sees number 9 and set temporary sum to 0.
5. repeat

For instance:

```
def addoutside(arrg, from_no=6, to_no=9):
    has_seen_from = False #has not seen a 6 yet
    confirmed_sum = 0 # final sum
    temp_sum = 0 # temporary sum

    for num in arrg:
        if num==from_no:
            has_seen_from = True

        elif num==to_no and has_seen_from:
            has_seen_from=False #reset 
            temp_sum = 0 #zero-out this value
            continue  #new iteration so the 9 won't count in the code below

        if has_seen_from:
            temp_sum+= num ## add to temp
        else:
            confirmed_sum+=num
    confirmed_sum += temp_sum ## add temporary to final because it never saw a 9 after a 6

    return confirmed_sum

addoutside([4,5,6,7,8,9,9])
Out[1] 18
```

Comment: You can use `elif` instead of `continue`

Comment: This is the correct answer if your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, True, there is some way to actually move the second `if-else` into the first to actually. Will update soon, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good solution I guess, It keep track of sum_after_six and subtracts it from total when it see 9.

But it resets the sum_after_six when it sees new 6, I don't know if you intended it? if not you can add one additional condition `if not seen_six and num==6` to reset the sum_after_six

Hope this helps

```py
arr = [4,5,6,7,8,9,9]
seen_six = False
total = 0
sum_after_six = 0
for num in arr:
    total += num
    sum_after_six +=num
    if num==6:
        seen_six = True
        sum_after_six = num
    elif seen_six and num==9:
        total -= sum_after_six
        sum_after_six = 0
        seen_six = False

print(total)
```

Comment: I'm confused a bit. The code works, but I'm having trouble understanding some of the aspects. The main I'm confused with is in line right above the first elif statement. At that point the value of sum_after_six is 40, because it equals to num. I'm confused as to how num == 40....

Comment: May be you have inspected "sum_after_six" before setting it to num. As you can see the code is continually adding "num" to "sum_after_six" but it is resetting it when it sees 6, at that time its value will be 6.  

so basically there will always be some value of "sum_after_six" but its gets ignored when it sees 6 at that time its value is set to 6

Answer (score -1):

Check this, I wrote some short comments, I think it's clear enough for you.

```py
def addoutside(a):        
    b = list(a)
    lb = len(b)
    check = False
    for i in range(lb):        
        if check:
            break
        elif b[i] ==6:
            for j in range(i, lb):  # This loop for remove all elements between 6 and 9, include them
                b.remove(b[j])      # remove 6
                while b[j]!=9:
                    b.remove(b[j])  # remove elements between 6 and 9
                if b[j]==9:
                    check = True
                    b.remove(b[j])  # remove 9
                    break

        else:
            pass
    print(b)
    return sum(b)

b = [4,5,6,7,8,9,9]
print(addoutside(b))
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 9]
18
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Your default argument is None for no good reason, and you modify the original list.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I don't see that he need to keep the original list. But I edited, thanks for reminding it.

Comment: It still has one downvoted, anyone tick it, please let me know what is the issue on my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear enough because you said excluding 6 and 9. How come you still say the expected output should be 18? if it is excluding 6 and 9; I think this is what your trying to solve:

```
  def addoutside(arg):
    sum_arg = 0;
    for num in arg:
        if num >= 6 and num <= 9:
            pass
        else:
            sum_arg += num
    return sum_arg

list_of_num = [4,5,6,7,8,9,9,6,7,8,9];
print(addoutside(list_of_num))
```

> This will output: 9

Comment: This function will work well no matter the type of input.

Comment: OP meant "betwee"n index-wise, not value-wise. In `6, 1, 2, 3, 9`, all elements should be discarded.